# Why can't I copy/paste or drag/drop into my virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, virtualhost, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a project, and I'm using Ubuntu Studio 14.10 inside Virtual Box (4.3.22; which is the latest version AFAIK).

I'd like to copy some files from my host (Windows 8.1) to the virtual machine, but I can't seem to make it work.
I've tried both "drag 'n' drop" and copy-paste, but neither work.

I have enabled both in the Virtual Box options:

[image]

[image]

**Why aren't copy/paste and drag 'n' drop working, even though they're enabled?**